# How could we plot graphical representation using High Charts where one x-axis value have multiple y-axis value

Tags: highcharts

How could we plot graphical representation using High Charts where one x-axis value have multiple y-axis value 
and for each x-axis value number of y-axis value differs.
I have date on x-axis and on y-axis the readings.
Now, i have data for each date, but the number of reading may differ for different dates. Like for today i have 5 readings and yesterday it was 10 readings.
So i have the data Date vise. and i want to plot it on graph with positive and negative values. I do some RnD for high charts for this, but highcharts dont show the reading receptive with this scenario, or may be i didnt get it. Can anybody help me in this.

Data I have:
1) Date: 1/8/2017
   Values:[12,56,-14,35,8] 
2) Date: 2/8/2017
   Values:[3,9,-4]
3) Date: 3/8/2017
   Values:[8,-6,45]

Thank you for the help

Comment: what did you do so far? please post your code also.

Comment: I try this, but not working for me, Because the data i have differs from their requirement .http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scatter series: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/scatter-chart

**Live demo adjusted to your problem:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/c6w79bd0/

If you have data composed similarly to this:

```
var data = [{
  date: Date.UTC(2017, 0, 1),
  values: [4, 5, 6, -2]
}, {
  date: Date.UTC(2017, 0, 2),
  values: [3, -7]
}, {
  date: Date.UTC(2017, 0, 3),
  values: [0, 11]
}];
```

You can prepare it this way:

```
var series = {
  data: []
};
data.forEach(function(day) {
    day.values.forEach(function (value){
    series.data.push([day.date, value]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution, need some more help, the example http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/c6w79bd0/ works perfect for me but on the hover of points its must show the proper date currently it was showing me some number. and one more Que. I have to show one more value with x and y on hover of each point which is unique for each [x,y] pair,  so can we to this also? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: You need to use tooltip.pointFormatter to convert timestamp to a human-readable date string. All point's options (properties assigned to it in JSON) can be accessed in formatter via this.options object. Both of these cases are solved in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/4o0t0amn/